# Iterate on an array with two implicit loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy, indexing

Is it possible to iterate implicitly on an array with two indices? 
Here is a very simple example of what I would like to do :

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3)
y = np.zeros(3)

for i in range(3):
    y[i] = np.sum(x - x[i])
```

There is an implicit loop (the sum) and an explicit one (`for i in range(3)`)... Is it possible to have a totally implicit version of that?

Comment: you can do it like this `y = np.array([sum(x - k) for k in x])` if it counts as `'implicit'`

Comment: This does speed it up a bit and looks nicer, @Roman, but I think thomleo is looking for a loop within numpy.

Comment: @askewchan ok, I still learning numpy, may be there's nicer way to do this, I will be glad to see it

Comment: @Roman my goal was to not have any python loop, but loop within numpy as askewchan said! Thanks anyway for your suggestion, it looks nicer that what I posted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When possible, you should always try to use mathematics before computer science. Your expression, `y[i] = np.sum(x - x[i])` can be rewritten with a little algebra as `y[i] = np.sum(x) - x.size * x[i]`. This makes it very clear that you can rewrite your code without any loops as:

```
y = np.sum(x) - x.size * x
```

As should be obvious, for large arrays it runs much faster than @JoshAdel's solution, x400 faster for an input of size 1000:

```
>>> x = np.random.normal(size=(1000,))
>>> np.allclose(np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1), np.sum(x) - x.size * x)
True

%timeit np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.33 ms per loop

%timeit np.sum(x) - x.size * x
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.5 us per loop
```

Comment: Although I'd say smarter algorithms are still within the purview of CS. +1 for recognizing the simpler and faster way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
y = np.sum(x - x[:,None], axis=1)
```

This solution is using numpy's broadcasting facility. First I'm recasting `x` which has a shape of `(N,)` to `(N,1)` using `x[:,None]`. You might also see this written as `x[:,np.newaxis]`.

`x - x[:,None]` creates an `(N,N)` array whose elements are `tmp_{i,j} = x_i - x_j`. I then just sum across the rows using the argument `axis=1` in `np.sum`.

See:

```
In [13]: y = np.zeros(10)

In [14]: x = np.random.normal(size=(10,))

In [15]: for i in range(10):
        y[i] = np.sum(x - x[i])
   ....:

In [16]: y
Out[16]:
array([  7.99781458,   4.15114434, -17.24655912, -20.35606168,
        -5.0211756 ,   7.52062868,   8.2501526 ,   3.90397351,
        10.18746451,   0.61261819])

In [17]: np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1)
Out[17]:
array([  7.99781458,   4.15114434, -17.24655912, -20.35606168,
        -5.0211756 ,   7.52062868,   8.2501526 ,   3.90397351,
        10.18746451,   0.61261819])

In [18]: np.allclose(y, np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1))
Out[18]: True
```

**Timings:** Just to point out that using the facilities that numpy provides to operate on arrays is often significantly faster than using standard Python constructs:

```
In [48]: x = np.random.normal(size=(100,))

In [49]: %timeit y = np.array([sum(x - k) for k in x])
100 loops, best of 3: 6.86 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit y = np.array([np.sum(x - k) for k in x])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 µs per loop

In [51]:

In [51]: x = np.random.normal(size=(1000,))

In [52]: %timeit y = np.array([sum(x - k) for k in x])
1 loops, best of 3: 592 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit y = np.array([np.sum(x - k) for k in x])
100 loops, best of 3: 17.2 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit np.sum(x - x[:,None], 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.67 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice!  The only disadvantage of this is that it builds a large 2d array in the process of shape `(x.size, x.size)`.

Comment: You could avoid the `-`ve if you sum along `axis=1`.

Comment: @askewchan When you're trying to get rid of loops in numpy, you often end up making large temporary arrays in order to vectorize the calculation. Also, I changed the summation to make it more intuitive. Realized it just before you posted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! As always... trade off memory against time!

Comment: @RomanPekar I added a description of how this works. It relies on numpy broadcasting